# if isset post with jquery (upload file)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

When i remove "if(isset($_POST['_upload_profile_image'])){}" from users.php. Code is working and uploading.

How can i do this with 'isset($_POST'.

MY JQUERY

```
$("#upload_profile_image").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/particley/global/post/users.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function (html) {

            if (html == 'true') {

                //                      

            } else {

               //

            }

        }
   });
}));
```

MY PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['_upload_profile_image'])){

    $upload = ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);               

    if ($users->upload($upload) === TRUE)  {

        echo 'true';

    } else {

        echo 'false';

    }

}
```

Comment: have u tried var dump $POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any element in your form having name `_upload_profile_image`, If not then remove this line

```
if(isset($_POST['_upload_profile_image'])){
```

or replace with

```
if(isset($_FILE['image']) && !empty($_FILE['image'])){
```

Comment: with works if(isset($_FILES['image']) && !empty($_FILES['image'])), thank you.

dont have any options with jquery edit?

Comment: you welcome, you can validate the form input in front end use `required` in your input element for HTML validation, for jquery validation you should use jquery validator https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this with your ph code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){

    $upload = ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);               

    if ($users->upload($upload) === TRUE)  {

        echo 'true';

    } else {

        echo 'false';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For File upload There are various methods available to check files exist or not you can use any of them.

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {

if ($_FILES['logo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { ... }

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
```

In your case you can use any of them :

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){

    $upload = ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);               

    if ($users->upload($upload) === TRUE)  {

        echo 'true';

    } else {

        echo 'false';

    }
}
```